# MySQL order by date then order by an id

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order my query results so that the row with the newest date is first in the result set. I also need for the query to then group all the `conversation_id`s together.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT conv.conversation_id, conv.user_id, conv.contact_id, msg.message_id, msg.message, msg.sent_date
FROM (SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY sent_date DESC) as msg
LEFT JOIN conversation AS conv
ON conv.contact_id = msg.contact_id
WHERE user_id = 24
ORDER BY conversation_id;
```

It does not sort correctly.

I get this table using the above query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGmVo.jpg

What I need is for the group with `conversation_id` 2 to be at the top. Changing the `ORDER BY` at the end of the query  to be `DESC` will not work for all values in the tables.

Comment: ....order by data desc, order by id asc - like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a friend and Gordon Linoff's answer. Below is the code that will work:

```
SELECT conv.conversation_id, conv.user_id, conv.contact_id,
       msg.message_id, msg.message, msg.sent_date
FROM message msg LEFT JOIN
     conversation conv
     ON conv.contact_id = msg.contact_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT conversation_id, MAX(sent_date) as max_msg_sent_date
      FROM message
      GROUP BY conversation_id
     ) mmax
     ON mmax.conversation_id = msg.conversation_id
WHERE user_id = 24
ORDER BY max_msg_sent_date desc, msg.conversation_id, msg.sent_date DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The subquery does nothing, except slow down your query.

You seem to want things ordered by conversations, but by the most recent conversation first.  If so, you need to bring that information into the query using an additional `join`:

```
SELECT conv.conversation_id, conv.user_id, conv.contact_id,
       msg.message_id, msg.message, msg.sent_date
FROM message msg LEFT JOIN
     conversation conv
     ON conv.contact_id = msg.contact_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT conversation_id, MAX(sent_date) as max_ent_date
      FROM message
      GROUP BY conversation_id
     ) mmax
     ON mmax.conversation_id = m.conversation_id
WHERE user_id = 24
ORDER BY mmax.max_sent_date desc, m.conversation_id;
```

Comment: @kennyjwilli . . . That doesn't make sense.  Everything with `conversation_id = 2` should have the same `max_msg_sent_date` because of the `join`.  Messages from the same conversation should be together.  Perhaps you should set up a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Actually wait you updated you answer.. I get a `Unknown column 'msg_sent_date' in 'field list'`. It seems like there are several names that do not point to anything in that query.

Comment: Got the answer fiddling around with your query. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ORDER BY conversation_id DESC, sent_date DESC` without the sub-query.

This will retrieve results in the decreasing order of conversation_id and in case of ties, will arrange them in descending order of their time. (If that is what you're looking for)

Comment: This does not work either: http://imgur.com/yaHxdbW I need for the "group" with `conversation_id` = 2 to be on the top because it has the newest message with a date of 2015-01-02

Comment: The issue with `GROUP BY` is I need all of the results, not just 1 result for each `coversation_id`

Comment: You can simply use [ORDER BY conversation_id DESC, sent_date DESC] to receive the newest conversations first. I'm assuming you have an auto-increment on your conversation id.

Comment: That works for the previous table except for when I add a new message to the table. Now I get: http://imgur.com/4QydBFN. It should have the "group" of 1's at the top now. And yes, `conversation_id` is set to auto increment.

Comment: My bad. You'll either have to use a GROUP BY or a LEFT JOIN to get the conversation id corresponding to the newest message. See this: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_groupby_2